# Errors are the lack of packages, classes and variables and methods

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm having trouble solving some problems with my files in Android Studio, I have two files where the comments I made point out the errors.

Some variables or code snippets are in PT-BR, because I am Brazilian from a Stack Overflow in Brazil, but there they do not help me much in terms of Android Studio.

**The errors are the lack of packages, classes and variables and methods.**

File `ListPessoas.java` (total of 4 errors)

```
package com.example.iury.livroapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; //error package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView; //error: package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist
import java.util.List;

public class ListarPessoas extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView; //error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_pessoas);
        setTitle("Listar pessoas");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); //error: cannot find symbol variable recyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        DatabaseHelperClass bd = new DatabaseHelperClass(this);
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = bd.getListarPessoas();

        if (pessoas.size() > 0){
            PessoaAdapter pessoaadapter = new PessoaAdapter(pessoas,ListarPessoas.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(pessoaadapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Não existe pessoas no banco de dados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

File `PessoaAdapter.java` (total of 12 errors)

```
package com.example.iury.livroapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull; //error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; //error: package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView; //error: package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist
import java.util.List;

                                  //error: package RecyclerView does not exist
public class PessoaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PessoaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Pessoa> pessoas;
    Context context;
    DatabaseHelperClass bd;

    public PessoaAdapter(List<Pessoa> pessoas, Context context) {
        this.pessoas = pessoas;
        this.context = context;
        bd = new DatabaseHelperClass(context);
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override //error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    //error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listar_pessoas,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    
    @Override
    //error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Pessoa f_pessoa = pessoas.get(position);

        holder.textId_pessoa.setText(Integer.toString(f_pessoa.getId_pessoa()));
        holder.editNome_pessoa.setText(f_pessoa.getNome_pessoa());
        holder.editEmail_pessoa.setText(f_pessoa.getEmail_pessoa());
        holder.editTelefone_pessoa.setText(f_pessoa.getTelefone_pessoa());

        holder.button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nome_pessoa = holder.editNome_pessoa.getText().toString();
                String email_pessoa = holder.editEmail_pessoa.getText().toString();
                String telefone_pessoa = holder.editTelefone_pessoa.getText().toString();

                bd.UpdatePessoa(new Pessoa(f_pessoa.getId_pessoa(),nome_pessoa,email_pessoa,telefone_pessoa));
                notifyDataSetChanged(); //error: cannot find symbol method notifyDataSetChanged()
                ((Activity) context).finish();
                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
            }
        });

        holder.button_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bd.DeletePessoa(f_pessoa.getId_pessoa());
                pessoas.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override //error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pessoas.size();
    }
                            //error: package RecyclerView does not exist
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Button button_update, button_delete;
        TextView textId_pessoa;
        EditText editNome_pessoa, editEmail_pessoa, editTelefone_pessoa;
        Button button_update_pessoa, button_delete_pessoa;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textId_pessoa = findViewById(R.id.textId_pessoa);
            editNome_pessoa = findViewById(R.id.editNome_pessoa); //error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
            editEmail_pessoa = findViewById(R.id.editEmail_pessoa);
            editTelefone_pessoa = findViewById(R.id.editTelefone_pessoa); //error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
            button_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_pessoa);
            button_update = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_update_pessoa);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The comments point to where the errors are, just remembering.

Comment: You're using the old and obsolete android support libraries and trying to import the new `androidx` libraries which is why you're getting the error. Either, migrate to `androidX` which is should be done or use android support libraries of these packages. To migrate to `androidX`, open build.gradle (app) file, right click anywhere on the code, go to refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX and let it process, then it will start working.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I'm using the Android Studio 3.1 version, sometimes the IDE itself doesn't help me much. My PC has a low configuration to run the most current version of Android Studio.

Comment: I'm not talking about the Android Studio, but the android support libraries you're using. You're using old android support libraries as `import android.widget.TextView;`, see the `android` and you're trying to import `androidx.annotation.NonNull;`, see the `androidx` here. For this, either you've to migrate to AndroidX (preferred way)or use the android libraries instead of androidx.